# Application crashes by installing APK while running from Android Studio works perfectly

Tags: android, android-studio

I recently updated Android Studio to 2.3 and SDK to 25. Now when I run application from Android Studio on my mobile or emulator it is working perfectly but when I generate APK or get APK from App and install on device it crashes.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "lovestar.lycamobile"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

}

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

}

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="lovestar.lycamobile">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/lycalogo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name="lovestar.lycamobile.MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="lovestar.lycamobile.Lyca"></activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Turn off `Instant run`, clean, build and generate apk. Give it a try.

Comment: check which version of mobile. might be your mobile OS version is 6.0 and emulator version is lower. So might be getting the permission issue. post your logcat

Comment: @ASIF RAZA, information you have provided in question is not sufficient to diagnose problem. Please share logcat with manifest file of your application. Thanks

Comment: Use Build APK option from Android Studio Menu and install APK in Mobile.

Comment: my mobile version is 5.1. and i have installed sdks 25 and 23.

Comment: I have API 23 installed and was having same problem in my 5.0 device, So try my solution

Comment: Try Invalidate Caches / Restart .. from File menu.

Comment: Usually it's AndroidManifest.xml problem that does not have proper package name or activity with MAIN intent was not properly defined. That's easy fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Possible/Common causes of “Application not Installed” error**

- **Insufficient storage space:** Your storage space may have filled up
  with no more space to accommodate new apps.
- **Corrupted app or apk file:** This is most common with apps downloaded from outside Google Play Store. The app is either corrupted or incompletely downloaded or copied as the case maybe.
- **Incorrect app install location:** Some apps are meant to be only installed on phone memory while some others can be installed on both phone memory and SD card. Trying do otherwise with the former can bring up this errors.
- **Installation on a mounted SD card:** Maybe, your SD card is mounted on a laptop or elsewhere. Trying to install anything in this state will result in errors because the SD card is inaccessible.
- **Corrupted storage (Phone and SD card):** This is probably the most common cause of this error. If the storage of your device is corrupted, any app installation will be impossible.
- **Apk signature/certificate clash:** Installing another version of an app (with a different signed certificate) on the same device will probably result in this error. Installing an unsigned app could also result in this error.
  App permission errors or temporary OS glitches could also bring about this error.

*I think you have not exported the APK in right way that's why you are getting this error.*

Comment: thanks its working now. after installing repository and build apk from android studio menu.

Answer (score 4):

I faced this problem 2-3 days ago. It happens because of Instant Run Feature. Most recent code of App is not properly build on APK So rebuild APK from Android Studio Menu

To solve this:

> 1. Use Build APK option from Android Studio Menu and install in Mobile.

If Above Step does nothing See Step 2

> 2. Usually it's AndroidManifest.xml problem that does not have proper
>      package name or activity with MAIN intent was not properly defined.
>      That's easy fix.

Comment: i have build apk and install it but it give "app not installed"

Comment: Can you share screenshot

Comment: i have share screen shot. if i run app from android studio its working but apk not working

Comment: provide  apk-debug not release

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138501/discussion-between-prashanth-and-asif-raza).

Comment: Usually it's AndroidManifest.xml problem that does not have proper package name or activity with MAIN intent was not properly defined. That's easy fix.

Answer (score 1):

Generate Signed APk and you will get rid of this problem.

Comment: My apk is already Signed but still getting the same error as mentioned.

Answer (score -2):

SDK Level 23 means Android 6.0 Marshmallow. Is your mobile's android version really equal to or grater than 6.0? To check this, open Setting app, scroll down, tap Informations, then software info. You'll se your Adnroid version at the top.

Comment: my mobile version is 5.1

Comment: So you cannot use this app normally on your device. Android studio uploads a debug into your phone, so you can continue but it's not possible normally. Change your API level to 21.

Comment: i dont have install sdk 21

Comment: So you have to install it. Open your SDK manager, select it and click install. SDKs are not down compatible. Like, if you have a phone with SDK level 21 and you have installed SDK 23, it won't run, but if you have a SDK level 23 mobile and SDK 21 installed, it will run perfectly.

Comment: in previous version of android studio i was using same mobile and same sdk and that was working perfectly

Comment: There are two SDK levels, really. They're called build version and target version. If your mobile meets build version, it'll be OK.